# Define \tableofcontents in document class that doesn't support it

Tags: table-of-contents, document-classes

I'm required to use the sigchi document class for a paper: https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats/blob/master/LaTeX/sigchi.cls

I'm also required to include a table of contents on the first page, but using the standard `\tableofcontents` produces a stack overflow:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@latexerr #1#2->\GenericError
```

Turns out a table of contents is usually prohibited in this template, as seen in the .cls file:

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@latexerr{\tableofcontents: Tables of contents are not
  allowed in the `acmconf' document style.}\@eha}
```

If I comment out this bit from the .cls file, I get an undefined control sequence error.

I guess, then, that the `\tableofcontents` command needs to be explicitly defined by a document class? In my case, it isn't. How do I add it? Would I be able to grab the source of the command definition from a standard `article` document class and stick it into my sigchi.cls? Or is there a package I could use?

**EDIT**

Here's a MWE with just a few sections. This will not compile as soon as you add a `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass{sigchi}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\tableofcontents` command is defined by the class, usually, but it is possible to use the usual definition as defined by `book.cls` etc., with caution however. Please show us a minimal version of your document that would compile if there is no `\tableofcontents`

Comment: A problem might still pop up: Do you plan to hand in this document as a paper? The editors might refuse the addition of a `\tableofcontents`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer My department has prescribed this for all theses (don't ask...). The sigchi class is normally used for short articles which obviously don't need a TOC, but for a thesis, a TOC is required.

Comment: What about `sigchi-ext` -- that class does have a `\tableofcontents`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks, but despite the naming, the extended abstracts class looks completely different visually. How do I find the definition of `\tableofcontents`, though? Cmd+f gets me nothing in sigchi-ext.cls.

Comment: Sorry but if someone **require** that you to use a specific cls then it is their responsability to ensure that the cls fullfils whatever they want. It is imho quite impertinent from your department to expect from you to hack a latex class to write your thesis.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm frustrated myself. But they're also providing a fully functional .docx template in addition the .cls files. So I can't complain :)

Comment: Sure you can complain. They should either force you to use the docx, or offer a sensible, working latex class, or simply tell you how the result should look. Forcing you to use a non-working cls is idiotic -- and as it means that they don't understand LaTeX code anyway you probably can simply ignore the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sigchi.cls` is not meant for a thesis, it misses several features 
necessary for typesetting a thesis (or has redefined it strangely)

The easiest way is to use a 'copy' of the `\tableofcontents` version provided by `article.cls`

Please note that the page layout is awkward, but this is another question too.

```
\documentclass{sigchi}

% Perhaps useful?
%\usepackage[paper=letterpaper]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}% For example
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \section*{\contentsname}
  \@starttoc{toc}
}

% sigchi.cls does \let\thepage\relax (don't ask!), so define it again
\newcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{First section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This works if I change `\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}` to `\newcommand{\tableofcontents}`, and `\newcommand{\thepage}` to `\renewcommand{\thepage}`.

Comment: @Elise: A, I forgot that you have disabled `\def\tableofcontents`. Better use the original version of the class again

Comment: And I'm absolutely aware that the template is unsuitable for a thesis... My complaints have been so far ignored :(

Comment: @Elise: I hope you will succeed with your thesis anyway. Perhaps using `article` or `memoir` miming the look of `sigchi` might be even better