# Unable to include tocloft package with custom document class

Tags: table-of-contents, document-classes, tocloft

I'm wrestling with a custom document class which I'm required to use for my thesis:

https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats/blob/master/LaTeX/sigchi.cls

It disallows having a table of contents by default, but I managed to define a basic one with the help of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346018/19179

My next problem is styling the TOC entries. I'm trying to include the `tocloft` package so that I can do `\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}` etc, but it fails with

```
! Extra \fi.
\@cfttocfinish ...f@restonecol \twocolumn \fi \fi
```

There must be something in either the .cls or the custom `tableofcontents` definition which it doesn't like?

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{sigchi}

\usepackage{tocloft}

% Redefine the table of contents because sigchi class is shit.
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346012/define-tableofcontents-in-document-class-that-doesnt-support-it?noredirect=1#comment849020_346012
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{Contents}}
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{
    \section*{\contentsname}
      \@starttoc{toc}
    }

% sigchi.cls does \let\thepage\relax (don't ask!), so define it again
\newcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}

\end{document}
```

The document compiles if either `\tableofcontents` or `\usepackage{tocloft}` is removed, but having both in there gives me the above error.

Comment: `sigchi.cls` is a bad, bad class ...

Comment: Try `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That works! I'm able to modify the fonts just before my appendix listings, too. The only problem is that the line heights in my TOC are now very stretched...

Comment: It is a by-passing solution at the moment only. Most likely you have to change the `\cftbeforeXskip` values, where `X` stands for `chapter` or `sec` etc. (see page 9 of current `tocloft` manual, please)

Comment: Small correction: It's `chap`, not `chapter`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sigchi.cls` does not really conform to a standard class and as such `tocloft`'s sophisticated features can't take grip off the class definitions.

The best is to activate the `titles` option of `tocloft` to prevent strange class definitions.

Whether this will be allowed by potential editors is another issue ;-)

```
\documentclass{sigchi}


\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

% Redefine the table of contents because sigchi class is ...
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346012/define-tableofcontents-in-document-class-that-doesnt-support-it?noredirect=1#comment849020_346012
\makeatletter
%\@cftnctoctrue
%\AtBeginDocument{%
\newcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
%}
\makeatother


% sigchi.cls does \let\thepage\relax (don't ask!), so define it again
\newcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}

\end{document}
```